# How to extract the 3 values using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

How to use `preg_match_all()` with this sample

```
<div class="b1 b2 A1 C7" style="right: 9px; top:5px;">
    <div class="tr">1</div>
</div>

<div class="b1 b2  A4 C2" style="right: 19px; top:5px;">
    <div class="tr">2</div>
</div>

<div class="b1 b2  A1 C4" style="right: 29px; top:5px;">
    <div class="tr">2</div>
</div>
```

I want to get these values

1. A**1** only The number after **A**
2. C**7** only The number after **C**
3. `<div class="tr">`**1**`</div>` only The number between **DIV**

This is what I've tried

```
preg_match_all('/A(.+?) C(.+?)| class="tr">(\d+)<\/div><\/div>/s', $str, $m);
```

but now work I don't want to use `preg_replace()` new line or whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work for your specific case:

```
preg_match_all('/A(\d+?)|C(\d+?)|\<div class="tr"\>(\d+?)\<\/div\>/s', $str, $m);
```

That return:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => A1
        [1] => C7
        [2] => <div class="tr">1</div>
        [3] => A4
        [4] => C2
        [5] => <div class="tr">2</div>
        [6] => A1
        [7] => C4
        [8] => <div class="tr">2</div>
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => 1
        [7] => 
        [8] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 7
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 2
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => 4
        [8] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 2
        [6] => 
        [7] => 
        [8] => 2
    )
```

Comment: Be welcome. If answer is useful for you ... can accept the answer ... check below the voting arrows

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you want is:

```
/A(\d+) C(\d+)[^<]+<div class="tr">(\d+)/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TVKkXB/1)

This pattern is much faster because it doesn't use any pipes (`|`) and it uses a negated character class to quickly move toward the final capture group.

It is also important to note that my pattern doesn't do any unnecessary character escaping.  The `\d` characters are just as safe in "greedy" mode so the `?`s can removed.

Since there are no `.`s in the pattern, the `s` flag has no purpose at the end of the regex pattern -- so I have removed it.

My pattern will complete in just 90 steps, compared to MTK's 741 steps.